# Why REC_Catch_Exception in one version but not the other?

Tags: java, exception, findbugs

In the first code (code1) findbugs finds a REC_catch_Exception warning because

```
try { ... } catch (Exception e)
```

is not a good style. But in the second code (code2) the warning disappears.

Why? The only difference is the type `setMatrikelnummer` takes: `Integer` vs. `String`.

```
        //code1: With REC_Catch_Exception 
        try {
                // set student datas
                currentStudent.setVorname(registration[0]);
                currentStudent.setName(registration[1]);
                currentStudent.setMatrikelnummer(Integer
                        .parseInt(registration[2]));
                currentStudent.setEmail(registration[3]);
                currentStudent.setAnrede(registration[4]);
                currentStudent.setStudiengang(registration[5]);

                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.UK);
                Date registrationDate = formatter.parse(registration[6]);
                currentRegistration.setRegistrationDate(registrationDate);

            } catch (Exception E) {
                throw new WrongFormatException(
                        "Die Textdateien befinden sich im falschen Format");
            }

        //code2: Without REC_Catch_Exception 
        try {
                // set student datas
                currentStudent.setVorname(registration[0]);
                currentStudent.setName(registration[1]);
                currentStudent.setMatrikelnummer(registration[2]);
                currentStudent.setEmail(registration[3]);
                currentStudent.setAnrede(registration[4]);
                currentStudent.setStudiengang(registration[5]);

                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.UK);
                Date registrationDate = formatter.parse(registration[6]);
                currentRegistration.setRegistrationDate(registrationDate);

            } catch (Exception E) {
                throw new WrongFormatException(
                        "Die Textdateien befinden sich im falschen Format");
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

When there are more than one exception in try-catch block, REC_Catch_Exception triggers. Perhaps in the first code, two exceptions are probable and REC_Catch_Exception triggers but in the second code only one exception is probable and no REC_Catch_Exception triggers/